# Can the following SQL or HTML code using CodeIgniter be improved / shorterned for readability?

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

The following code segment works, but I feel that it can be further improved by being shortened and thus more efficient, but I'm struggling to think of what can be modified.

**Below is the code.**

```
function get_student_stakeholder_refs($debate_id) {
     $sql1    = "SELECT
              b.id            AS debates_id,
              c.id            AS stakeholder_id,
              a.student_id    AS student_id
            FROM
              debate_groups a
              inner join debates b ON a.debate_id = b.id
              inner join debate_stakeholders c ON a.stakeholder_id = c.id
            WHERE
              b.starter_pack_id = c.starter_pack_id AND 
              a.debate_id = b.id AND 
              b.id = ? AND 
              a.student_id = ?";
    $rslt = $this->db->query($sql1, array($debate_id, $this->get_user_id()))->row();
    if(count($rslt)!= 0){
        $sql2  = "SELECT * FROM debate_stakeholder_profiles WHERE stakeholder_id = ?";
        return $this->db->query($sql2, array($rslt->stakeholder_id))->result_array();
    }
}
```

> Is there a way to combine the following SQL statements into a single
>   SQL statement so that it's easier to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you don't need the second SQL statement since you can just fetch the whole row in the join in the first statement. Just replace this:

```
c.id            AS stakeholder_id,
```

With this:

```
c.*
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the name 'stakeholder_id' with your solution? It breaks a few things in my code,

Comment: No, you can't give the column an alias if you're selecting the whole row. If you really don't want to change it consider altering the result row directly. Like, say: $rslt->stakeholder_id = $rslt->id;

Comment: Thank you! Works beautifully.